# Printing variable from one module to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As part of my coursework for computing I need to create a program that gives solutions to problems on a device. For task 3 I would like to use a modified version of my task 2 as part of it as a module instead of coding a it again, I keep on coming up with errors can any one help with this code?

**Task 3 code:**

```
from random import randint
from task2 import trouble2
caseNo = randint(999,10000)

def main():

    devType = input("What type of device is it? ")
    devType = devType.lower()#converts the input devType to be lowercase

    text_file = open(str(caseNo)+".txt", "a")#opens/creates the file with the name that caseNo is and appends to it
    text_file.write(devType+"\n")#appends devtype to the file
    text_file.close()#closes the file

    devMake = input("What is the make of the device? ")
    devMake = devMake.lower()

    text_file = open(str(caseNo)+".txt", "a")
    text_file.write(devMake+"\n")
    text_file.close()

    devModel = input("What is the model of the device? ")

    text_file = open(str(caseNo)+".txt", "a")
    text_file.write(devModel+"\n")
    text_file.close()

    devMemory = input("How much memory does the phone have in GB? ")

    text_file = open(str(caseNo)+".txt", "a")
    text_file.write(devMemory+"\n")
    text_file.close()

main()
task2.trouble2()
global start
print(start)
```

**Task 2 code**

```
from time import * #imports the time module
import os #imports the os module
import datetime #imports the date and time module


def trouble2():
    global start
    smashed = ['shattered', 'smashed', 'cracked'] #creates a list called smashed
    wifi = ['internet', 'conection', 'wifi'] #creates a list called wifi
    button = ['home', 'lock', 'button'] #creates a list called button
    temp = ['high', 'hot', 'cold', 'boiling', 'freezing', 'low', 'temp', 'temperature'] #creates a list called temp
    virus = ['virus', 'slow', 'bug'] #creates a list called virus
    wet = ['wet', 'water', 'damp', 'moist', 'soaking'] #creates a list called wet
    charge = ['low', 'battery', 'charge'] #creates a list called charge
    headphones = ['3.5mm', 'headphone', 'jack'] #creates a list called headphones
    bent = ['bent', 'warped', 'arched'] #creates a list called bent
    sound = ['volume', 'quiet', 'loud', 'silent', 'speaker', 'sound', 'sounds'] #creates a list called sound
    frozen = ['frozen', 'stuck', 'stopped']
    exits = ['bye' 'exit']
    date = [] #creates an empty list called date
    today = datetime.date.today()
    date.append(today) #adds the current date to the list date


##    print("Welcome to tech support the date today is",date[0]) #prints welcome line and the date
##    sleep(2) #pauses the program for 2 seconds
    start = input("What is the problem with your phone? ") #creates an input for the user to state the problem

    questionL = start.lower() # changes the name of a variable and makes it lower case

    phrase = questionL.split() # splits up the phrase to help in later code

    for words in phrase: #checks to see if phrase is empty
        if words in smashed: #checks to see if words contains anything from the list smashed
            #os.system('ohdear.jpeg') #opens a picture in the default program
            #sleep(10) #pauses the program for 10 seconds
            with open('task 2 solutions.txt') as f:
                l = []
                for lines in f:
                    l.append(lines)
                print(l[1])
                sleep(1)
                print(l[2])
                sleep(5)


        elif words in wet:
            with open('task 2 solutions.txt') as f:
                l = []
                for lines in f:
                    l.append(lines)
                print(l[17])
                sleep(1)
                print(l[18])
                sleep(1)
                print(l[19])
                sleep(5)
            pass
        elif words in wifi:
            with open('task 2 solutions.txt') as f:
                l = []
                os.system('tech.jpg')
                sleep(4)
                for lines in f:
                    l.append(lines)
                print(l[4])
                sleep(1)
                print(l[5])
                sleep(5)
            pass
        elif words in button:
            with open('task 2 solutions.txt') as f:
                l = []
                for lines in f:
                    l.append(lines)
                print(l[7])
                sleep(1)
                print(l[8])
                sleep(5)
            pass

        elif words in temp:
            with open('task 2 solutions.txt') as f:
                l = []
                os.system('hot.gif')
                sleep(7)
                for lines in f:
                    l.append(lines)
                print(l[10])
                sleep(1)
                print(l[11])
                sleep(1)
                print(l[12])
                sleep(5)
            pass


            sleep(5)
            pass

        elif words in virus:
            with open('task 2 solutions.txt') as f:
                l = []
                for lines in f:
                    l.append(lines)
                print(l[14])
                sleep(1)
                print(l[15])
                sleep(5)
            pass

        elif words in charge:
            with open('task 2 solutions.txt') as f:
                l = []
                for lines in f:
                    l.append(lines)
                print(l[21])
                sleep(1)
                print(l[22])
                sleep(1)
                print(l[23])
                sleep(5)
            pass

        elif words in headphones:
            with open('task 2 solutions.txt') as f:
                l = []
                for lines in f:
                    l.append(lines)
                print(l[25])

            pass

        elif words in bent:
            with open('task 2 solutions.txt') as f:
                l = []
                for lines in f:
                    l.append(lines)
                print(l[27])
                sleep(1)
                print(l[28])
                sleep(1)
                print(l[29])
                sleep(5)
            pass


        elif words in sound:
            with open('task 2 solutions.txt') as f:
                l = []
                for lines in f:
                    l.append(lines)
                print(l[31])
                sleep(1)
                print(l[32])
                sleep(5)
            pass

        elif words in frozen:
            with open('task 2 solutions.txt') as f:
                l = []
                for lines in f:
                    l.append(lines)
                print(l[34])
                sleep(1)
                print(l[35])
                sleep(5)
            pass
        elif words in exits:
            exit()


        else:
            print("That solution is not covered by the program sadly but we have noted this down for the technition to deal with.")
```

This is the error I keep coming up with in Task 3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\Task 3 (1).py", line 35, in <module>
    task2.trouble2()
NameError: name 'task2' is not defined
```

Comment: The formatting isn't of stack overflow isn't making it display correctly

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  - posting all your code isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've imported `trouble2` from `task2` into the local namespace so you just call it:

```
from task2 import trouble2
...
trouble2()
```

If you `import task2` then you would call it:

```
import task2
...
task2.trouble2()
```

Comment: Thank you but how would i get the start variable to be printed to the same text files as the others in the code of task 3?

Comment: Avoid the use of global variables, just return it from `trouble2`, e.g. `start = trouble2()`.

Comment: I have tried that: start = trouble2()
text_file = open(str(caseNo)+".txt", "a")
text_file.write(start+"\n")
text_file.close()         how ever i came  up with this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\Task 3 (1).py", line 37, in <module>
    text_file.write(start+"\n")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: You may need to read some introductory python instruction. You need to `return start` from `trouble2()`.